# Android Facebook login after token expired

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, android-facebook

Basically the documentation says:

> When the access_token expires, the user will be seen as "logged out"
>   by Facebook. Your app will go through the same process as the first
>   time, but the user may not.

I trigger Facebook login on button click like that:

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(LoginActivity.this, permissions);
```

If I see that my token expired, I can probably call the same method and login user back, just like the documentation says (without any action from the user). But in case if user removed my app permissions from the settings, this call will show Facebook "authorize app" screen. It will look like I am forcing user to login using Facebook.

Question: is there a way to know if my app still has access to user's profile?

Answer (score 0):

In the scenario you are describing, the user will only be prompted with the dialog again if they consciously went into their Facebook settings before, and un-authorized the app.
In that case I think it's OK to prompt the user with the dialog again. If they don't want to authorize your app again, they can always reject the login dialog.

In summary: No, there is no way for you know whether a user un-authorized your app before renewing a token by using `LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(LoginActivity.this, permissions);`.